# On Aquarius M10 Ubuntu Tablet-- Terminal-Created Files Aren't Recognized By Gedit and LibreOffice

Tags: ubuntu-touch, tablet, vi, aquaris

When I use the Aquarius M10 with the Terminal app, I can use the "vi" command in the Terminal to create a file and save it in $HOME.

When I subsequently launch Gedit, the "Open File" dialogue in Gedit does not list the text file I created in "vi", even when the "All Files" option is selected.

Hence, I can't use Gedit to open the text file.

Similarly, I can't open the file in Libre Office writer. Is there some way to configure Ubuntu Touch so that the file-open dialogues will recognise the files?

Comment: What did you save it as (full file name, extension), were you running vi as root? Can you see it in nautilus / files?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that Gedit can only operate in the sandboxed environment which seems to be common to the other desktop apps, too. Try to move the vi created file  under

```
.local/share/libertine-container/user-data/puritine/
```

which seems to be the sandboxed home.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to reproduce the problem on my M10 saving a file named foo.txt in /home/phablet. I cant see it in file manager and have chmodded to 777.

Moving the file to the location specified by Max Chinni causes it to show up in /home/phablet from gedit and it then opens fine.